# For each row calculate ration of rows with higher value

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a table `A`. It has two columns `seller_id` and `cnt`

```
+-----------+------+
| seller_id |  cnt |
+-----------+------+
|        55 |    7 |
|       243 |    7 |
|       456 |    9 |
|       522 |   23 |
+-----------+------+
```

For each `seller_id` and `cnt` i need to calculate a ration of rows with `cnt` > current `cnt`

Currently i do it like this:

```
SELECT
    A.*,
    1-(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE cnt >= A.cnt )/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A )  
FROM 
    A
```

But it takes very long time to execute.

How can it be re-written to execute more efficiently?

**Update**
Doing the following helped a bit. But still not good enough. It is still N^2 operations.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A into @count;

SELECT
    A.*,
    1-(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE cnt >= A.cnt )/@count  
FROM 
    A
```

Comment: how about `select *, count(*) as newcnt ... group by seller_id having newcnt > cnt`?

Comment: But that would only give the count, not ration, right? I need that exact count to be divided by the total number of records (for each row)

Comment: If you want faster you shoot for a pre-computed table that is maintained by triggers

Comment: Good suggestion :) But this table is a result of some other computation :)

Comment: Then ask *that* question :p Regardless, same diff. I love it when people ultimately say: "well, I simplified it so you could understand it as it is way more complex than this"